# pandas - linear regression of dataframe columns values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, regression

I have a pandas dataframe `df` like:

```
A,B,C
1,1,1
0.8,0.6,0.9
0.7,0.5,0.8
0.2,0.4,0.1
0.1,0,0
```

where the three columns have sorted values [0,1]. I'm trying to plot a linear regression over the three series. So far I was able to use `scipy.stats` as following:

```
from scipy import stats

xi = np.arange(len(df))

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,df['A'])
line1 = intercept + slope*xi
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,df['B'])
line2 = intercept + slope*xi
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,df['C'])
line3 = intercept + slope*xi

plt.plot(line1,'r-')
plt.plot(line2,'b-')
plt.plot(line3,'g-')

plt.plot(xi,df['A'],'ro')
plt.plot(xi,df['B'],'bo')
plt.plot(xi,df['C'],'go')
```

obtaining the following plot:

[image]

Is it possible to obtain a single linear regression that summarize the three single linear regressions within `scipy.stats`?

Comment: If you want a regression that summarizes the three regressions, why not combine all the data and do linear regression on that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
x = pd.np.tile(xi, 3)
y = pd.np.r_[df['A'], df['B'], df['C']]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
line4 = intercept + slope * xi

plt.plot(line4,'k-')
```